# Invalid Key Length After Upgrading to NodeJS 6

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

The following Code to encrypt and decrypt requests to our payment gateway service works correctly with Node Js 5.7.0

```
function Encrypt(plainText, workingKey) {
    var m = crypto.createHash('md5');
    m.update(workingKey);
    var key = m.digest('binary');
    var iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f';    
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);    
    var encoded = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encoded += cipher.final('hex');
    return encoded;
};


function Decrypt(encText, workingKey) {
    var m = crypto.createHash('md5');
    m.update(workingKey)
    var key = m.digest('binary');
    var iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f';
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    var decoded = decipher.update(encText, 'hex', 'utf8');
    decoded += decipher.final('utf8');
    return decoded;
};
```

However after upgrading to NodeJS 6.0 (also tried 6.1) we get the following error.

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
Error: Uncaught error: Invalid key length
at Error (native)
at new Cipheriv (crypto.js:184:16)
at Object.Cipheriv (crypto.js:182:12)
```

Our key length has always been 16 characters (i.e 128 bits) and was working before the upgrade. Why would this problem be happening now?

Comment: 6.x is far from stable build, is it neccesary to use it? We are using 5.5.0 in our company, I tried 6.x too, but in an hour I was forced to go back.

Comment: Why do you use "binary" strings at all? Just use a Buffer and be done with it; remove the `'binary'` from `m.digest('binary')`.

Comment: @Artjom-b. Thank you very much. What you suggested worked. Would you be kind enough to explain why it worked ?

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I would think that storing binary data in a string of some (unknown) encoding is bound to lead to problems. My guess is that the default encoding changed in the new version. A Buffer is made for holding binary data, so it really should be used here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am posting the answer here in the hope it might help someone.

The problem seems to be caused due to using 'binary' digest for the key.
The solution is to simply call the digest function and store the key as a buffer instead.

The fixed code reads as

```
function Encrypt(plainText, workingKey) {
    var m = crypto.createHash('md5');
    m.update(workingKey);
    var key = m.digest();
    var iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f';    
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);    
    var encoded = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encoded += cipher.final('hex');
    return encoded;
};
```

My thanks to @Artjom-b for the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the solution.  I had the exact same problem, except with the IV. In my case the exception claimed the IV length was invalid, despite it being 16 bytes.  Switching from a binary string to a Buffer fixed the problem.

Comment: I made this change but now its showing Error 10001 when redirected to ccavenue server.